# "Home" link not visible on English and Arabic website

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, variations

I have created a site with two variations:

1. English
2. Arabic

I created several pages in English such as Page1, Page2 etc. All pages are visible on the navigation except the Home page.
I have set the navigation in such a way that English site will only display English site links. Similarly only pages created in Arabic site are displayed in it.
But in both cases "Home" link clicking on which will take user to respective site is not displayed. All other site pages are displaying fine.

I don't want to display "Home" link which will take user to parent site but its respective site.

Comment: How do you display link? User control? Custom one? Some code will be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: I am using <SharePoint:AspMenu>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding a new "heading" in navigation from Look and Feel --> Navigation